# Angular2 host: { '[routerLink]': '/foo' }

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Im trying to bind `routerLink` property to `a` element using **@Component.host.'[routerLink]'** declaration but it crashes:

> **EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property ("[ERROR ->]"): HostMatch@0:0**

It works fine with 
`template: '<a [routerLink]="['/Matches', 'MatchesDetail', { match: id }]">{{id}}</a>'`

Component code:

```
import { RouterLink } from 'angular2/router'

@Component({
    directives: [RouterLink],
    selector: 'a[match]',
    template: `{{id}}`,
    host: {
        '[routerLink]': "['/Matches', 'MatchesDetail', { match: id }]"
    }
})
```

The point is to get HTML like this:

***`<a href="/matches/1234">1234</a>`***

Instead of :

***`<match><a href="/matches/1234">1234</a></match>`***

What do I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Could you give the way you use this component? Thanks!

Comment: What's the purpose of adding it to `host:` anyway?

Comment: It can be `<a match></a>` somewhere in parent component template. Im using this component via DCL `this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(Match, this.elementRef, 'componentAnchor')`

Comment: You want to make the component itself a `routerLink`? I don't think this will work. You need to add it to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `routerLink` this way is just invalid. There is no support to use `routerLink` this way. It is a directive to be added to an element tag, not some special binding syntax.

```
host: {
    '[routerLink]': "['/Matches', 'MatchesDetail', { match: id }]"
}
```