# Angular routerLink HostBinding

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink, angular2-hostbinding

I want to add a routerLink to the Host Element in an Angular Component like this:

```js
@HostBinding('routerLink') routerLink = '/my-route'
```

But when I click the component, it wont navigate to the specified route. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible with Angular 11?

EDIT:
I also tried the old way of host binding (that is not recommended by tslint: `Use @HostBinding or @HostListener rather than the` host `metadata property (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-06-03) (no-host-metadata-property)tslint(1)`:

```js
host: {
  '[routerLink]': '[\'/my-route\']'
},
```

There is no router navigation following this either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 host: { '\[routerLink\]': '/foo' }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171195/angular2-host-routerlink-foo)

Comment: @Kordrad thanks for your reply! I've tried it this way with the same results, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a confusion of terms - `routerLink` is a directive which has a property (of the same name) - however, the way you are using it, your expectation is that the component itself has a property called `routerLink` - but it doesn't.

The proper way to use `routerLink` is to add it as an Angular directive to an element or component in an Angular template:

```html
<some-component routerLink="..."></some-component>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So there is no way to do what I'm trying to achieve then? I specifically didn't want to put the routerLink on the tag because then I would have to add it everywhere I use my component. I wanted it to get added on the host element of my component so I wouldn't have to add another div in my components html.

Comment: You could listen on the click event, see @user1313805 's answer

Comment: Oh that's your own answer :) - well that's a good way

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get a navigation working programmatically on the component itself so far is like this:

```js
@HostListener('click')
onClick($event): void {
  this.router.navigate(['/my-route'])
}
```